# Suggestions on how my end users can extract data using my SQL query without having to use SQL?

Tags: python, sql-server, excel, vba

The problem is that I've ended up with the extra role of having to run these queries for different users everyday because no one in our factory knows how to use SQL and my IT wouldn't grant them database access anyway.

I've consulted some tech savvier friends who have suggested that i create a GUI (using python) that does the querying for me? That sounds like it would be ideal since all my end users would have to do is key into an input field someone on the interface and the query would run, versus them querying for the data directly and potentially messing up my SQL script.

I've read online as well of the possibility of doing something like mentioned before but in Excel instead. Right now I'm just really lost as to where to start. I probably would need to do alot of reading up anyway but it'd be at least nice to know what is a good direction to start. Any new suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can create some reports in SSRS, then you don't need to create your own GUI.

Comment: use the views they are read only so you can create users with specific permissions to reach them (and only then) then you can also display the data in a very basic tool i.e. an excel sheet https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx/

Comment: Perhaps package your queries as stored procedure and then use Excel to execute them? But be aware that this approach requires that they access the database directly - something your IT group apparently does not desire. For others to "run your query" they must have access and that implies you would need to somehow embed your ID/password into any mechanism you provide. If permissions are **not** based on sql server logins, this might be a much bigger issue.

Comment: Thanks all, i ended up going with the stored procedure and got our IT group to create view-only accounts for end users.

Answer (score 0):

This could be overkill for you, but [Metabase](https://www.metabase.com/) is basically a GUI you can pretty easily set up on top of your SQL database.

It's target audience is "business analytics", so it enables people to create "questions" (aka. queries) using a GUI rather than writing SQL (although it allows raw SQL). More relevant to you, you probably just want to preconfigure some "questions" your users can log in and run in Metabase.

Without writing any code at all you could set up Metabase, write the query you want using either raw SQL or their GUI, and parameterize the query with some `user_id` or something the users can fill in. From there, you could give the users access to your Metabase (via the web), where they can go in and use the GUI to fill in whatever they need to and then run the query you've created for them.

Metabase also has a lot of customization, so you can make sure they only have permissions to see certain data, etc., and they don't need DB credentials. You, the Metabase admin, connect the database when you set up Metabase and give other users Metabase logins instead.